# Codeigniter form_open_multipart() displays blank

Tags: forms, file, codeigniter, upload

Been trying out codeigniter and wanted to create a very simple single file upload using the upload class. However I keep getting a blank page when trying to create a form using form_open_multipart. I've been looking around, but I can't seem to find out how to make this work.

The HTML uploadPage.php

```
<body>


    <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/theUpload');?>
    <input type="file" name="userfile">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File">
    </form>

</body>
```

The controller upload.php

```
<? if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class upload extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->load->view("uploadPage");

    }

    function theUpload(){


    }       





}
```

Comment: maybe you forgot to load Form helper. `$this->load->helper('form');`

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo thank you, that did it. THis video tutorial I was watching, they didn't include it. Oh well. Thanks!